# UITextField : restrict the maximum allowed value (number) during inputting

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField`, I'd like to restrict the maximum allowed input value in the field to be 1000. That's when user is inputting number inside, once the input value is larger than 999, the value in input field won't be updated anymore unless user is inputting value less than 1000.

I think I should use `UITextField` delegate to limit the input:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  //How to do
}
```

But I am not sure how to implement it. Any suggestions?

**==========Update=============**

my input field not only allow user to input integer, but also float value like 999,03

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should do the following inside the above method:

```
NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

//first, check if the new string is numeric only. If not, return NO;
NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789,."] invertedSet];
if ([newString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:characterSet].location != NSNotFound)
{
    return NO;
}

return [newString doubleValue] < 1000;
```

Comment: Don't forget to check if `replaced` contains an `int`, because `intValue` return `0` when it starts with other characters (e.g. `"hello"`).

Comment: That's true! I will update the answer. But considering the keyboard is set correctly (number pad), there is no need to worry about that.

Comment: What does stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString: actually doing? What is the 'withString' ?

Comment: It generates the string that would be replaced in case you return YES. It 'mixes' the current text with the newly inserted text, in the right position, and gives you the result. So you generate it, analyze, and in case it's ok, you just return YES.

Comment: Actually, my input field not only allow user to input integer, but also double value like 999,03, how to take this kind of value into account?

Comment: I tried your code, but my app get stuck when user input the 1st digit, xcode shows me "Thread 1 break point 1.1" at the line of 'stringByReplacingCharactersInRange', console output 'lldb'

Comment: The code should work without problems. Are you using breakpoints? The blue "arrow" in the number of the line in the code...

Comment: Hi, Natan R. it works now, but why I'm not able to input "," from my number keyboard now? User should be able to input e.g. "999,99"

Comment: That was because I put there a check for numbers only. Updated the answer, check the new NSCharacterSet. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField.tag == 3)
    {
        if(textField.text.length >3 && range.length == 0)
        {
            return NO;
        }
        else
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a class with the help method that can be call from any place in your project.

Swift code:

```
class TextFieldUtil: NSObject {

    //Here I am using integer as max value, but can change as you need
    class func validateMaxValue(textField: UITextField, maxValue: Int, range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let newString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

        //if delete all characteres from textfield
        if(newString.isEmpty) {
            return true
        }

        //check if the string is a valid number
        let numberValue = Int(newString)

        if(numberValue == nil) {
            return false
        }

        return numberValue <= maxValue
    }
}
```

Then you can use in your uiviewcontroller, in textfield delegate method with any textfield validations

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if(textField == self.ageTextField) {
        return TextFieldUtil.validateMaxValue(textField, maxValue: 100, range: range, replacementString: string)
    }
    else if(textField == self.anyOtherTextField) {
        return TextFieldUtils.validateMaxValue(textField, maxValue: 1200, range: range, replacementString: string)
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if([string length])
{
  if (textField == txt)
  {
      NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
      return !([newString length] > 1000);
  }                     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In its most basic form you can do this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString:(NSString*)string
{
    NSString* newText;

    newText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    return [newText intValue] < 1000;
}
```

However, you also need to check if `newText` is an integer, because `intValue` returns 0 when the text starts with other characters.